# VBA to insert a carriage return after existing text and paste more text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba

I'm adding "Measure_1" within certain cells. This requires me to double click in the cell, go to the end of the existing text, insert a carriage return (alt+ent), and then paste in MEASURE_1. Therefore, I'm trying to automate this.

Unfortunately my VBA code below is overwriting the existing text with the example I used when recording my macro.

```
activecell.FormulaR1C1 = "D4)" & Chr(10) & "MEASURE_1"
```

How do I make it say:

```
activecell.FormulaR1C1 = **ANY TEXT WITHOUT CHANGING** & Chr(10) & "MEASURE_1"
```

Many thanks.
Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `activecell.FormulaR1C1 = activecell.FormulaR1C1 & Chr(10) & "MEASURE_1"`